# Opening cshtml on kendo grid edit button click

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I'm trying to find a way to open a partial view inside the pop up window that opens up on kendo grid edit button click and I can't find any solution to this. Even if I create a "edit" function separately on the grid it gets fired on "Add" button as well can anyone assist me with this?

I have tried creating custom buttons like [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/OwoCIRus) but these are also visible on "Add new record" popup. is there a way to have a completely separate functionality on edit button click?

Comment: So your question is about how to conditionally show/hide the button or give it different behavior? Handle the databound event and apply your logic: https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-hide-command-buttons-for-select-rows

Comment: Hi @SteveGreene , Actually I have a kendo hierarchy grid in a partial view which is working. Now I want to show that partial view on another kendo grid editor but it should only display if I click on the "edit" button of the grid and not on the "Add" button.